# Why does Lorelei shoot Jason Lennon in S05E16?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mentalist

In the episode "There Will Be Blood" (*The Mentalist*, S05E16), Lorelei tracks down the people she believes to be behind her sister's abduction and murder, and exacts revenge. The second culprit (*Jason*) admits to being an accomplice of Red John, confirming that it was actually Red John who killed her sister.

After her worst fear comes true, Jane asks Lorelei to give up Red John's real identity, as was their deal. Lorelei, in turn, refuses to do so and asks Jane to get that name from Jason. She says:

> He'll talk. He's weak.

and later shoots Jason.

I fail to get her motivation to kill Jason there. Why does she do this? Moreover, after she has shot Jason, there is no emotional outburst on Jane's part. Shouldn't he go berserk now that Lorelei has refused to give him Red John and also shot his solid lead?

Comment: May be because jason helped RedJohn in the murder of her sister.

Comment: Yes, that would be the apparent and obvious answer. But am asking people to think deeper. Why ask Jane to get Red John from Jason and **then** shoot him?

Comment: No reason, because this show is not Breaking bad, or Dexter etc. To talk about the faulty logics of this tv show, i'm afraid we're gonna have to spend the rest of our life. 
I've watched all 6 seasons, not because i like it, it's because curiosity, you watched the first, then you have to finish the 2nd, that's what i hate about TV shows, like marrying the wrong one and you're not MAN enough to file a divorce

Answer (score 1):

I think that Lorelei wants to kill Red John herself before Jane gets his hand on Red John.

Comment: That could be one plausible answer. I think an elaboration is in order.

Answer (score 1):

In that chapter Lorelei also says:

> He's got weaknesses. He can die. And I'm gonna kill him

So this explains why she shot Jason, so that he won't reveal who is Red John and thus cause his arrest/death before she has chance to revenge her sister's murder.